# How to remove classes added to Woocommerce li.product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

Woocommerce adds the assigned product categories and attributes as custom classes to li.product

```
<li class="post-120 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail 
category1 category2 category3 category4 pa_one pa_two...">
```

We have assigned quite a lot of categories to each product and it slows down the site. Is there a way to remove those additional classes?

Comment: and how does several classes slow down the site? did you make any perfomance tests?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan yes, it sounds weird but we are talking about hundreds of classes from assigned categories (hierarchies) and attributes added to each product. I changed <li <?php //post_class(); ?> class="product"> in content-product.php. That did the trick and immediately reduced loading times by about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know php, You can edit the woocoommerce php template file to remove those additional classes.
If you opened the file,  there is a php variable to be added additional classes and it is a array.

Comment: You should provide the name of (and where to find) the file  in question.

Comment: content-product.php

Comment: @JinHuang saw your comment too late but you are right, content-product.php is where we changed this line <li <?php //post_class(); ?> class="product"> and that solved it.

Comment: Ping me anytime if you need me :)

Answer (score 6):

In the woocommerce plugin '3.6.2' the file 'wc-template-functions.php' it says:

// Note, to change classes you will need to use the newer woocommerce_post_class filter.

So to remove 'first' & 'last' classes I used:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'remove_post_class', 21, 3 ); //woocommerce use priority 20, so if you want to do something after they finish be more lazy
function remove_post_class( $classes ) {
    if ( 'product' == get_post_type() ) {
        $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'last','first' ) );
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

For product categories I used:

```
add_filter( 'product_cat_class', 'remove_category_class', 21, 3 ); //woocommerce use priority 20, so if you want to do something after they finish be more lazy
function remove_category_class( $classes ) {
    if ( 'product' == get_post_type() ) {
        $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'last','first' ) );
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest applying a filter to the post_class function instead of editing the template as woocommerce updates these regularly and can be a pain to keep on top of them. To do this you could check to see if you in the product loop or if a product exists to also remove from the product page like this :

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function($classes){
$product = wc_get_product();
return ($product) ? array('product'  'or-any-class-you-want') : $classes; } , 9999 );
```