# WooCommerce: Add class to product loop item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add some Bootstrap styles to the product item in the loop.

I know, that there is an extra template for that. And inside the template file `content-product.php` I could add some code to the `wc_product_class` function. Like this:

```
<li <?php wc_product_class( 'col-6 col-lg-4', $product ); ?>>
```

But now the class is added to every loop item in the shop. Like on the single product template inside the related products.

I know I could add some if/else and check on which page I am and add the styles for every page.
But I wonder if there is a better solution. Is there any way to add the class programmatically or hook the function?

In this case I could change/add the class only if I'm in the loop for example and I don't have to add a lot of code in the template file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could definitely leverage a filter here, but for controlling it for placement, you may need to do some `remove_filter` after it runs in the event it starts to bleed into other parts of the page.

So for the `wc_product_class` function, it makes a call to `wc_get_product_class` which ends up leveraging the filter hook of `post_class`. If you want to control the classes using this, you'll probably want to hook on that.

The filter ([seen here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_product_class.html#550-658)) takes 3 arguments:

`$classes` : The array of class names to be added

`$class` : An array or string of class names that are being added, in this case 'col-6 col-lg-4'.

`$post_id`: The post ID/ Product ID being used.

You'll probably need to write something like the following:

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes, $class, $product_id) {
    if(is_product_category()) {
        //only add these classes if we're on a product category page.
        $classes = array_merge(['col-6','col-lg-4'], $classes);
    }
    return $classes;
},10,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the woocommerce plugin '3.6.2' the file 'wc-template-functions.php' it says:

// Note, to change classes you will need to use the newer woocommerce_post_class filter.

My full answer is here:

[Full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546487/how-to-remove-classes-added-to-woocommerce-li-product/)